# Fix the bug! (how to call an asynchronous function inside a synchronous function)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, synchronous

The following question is taken from an interview. I was able to solve some parts, but I got stuck:

Fix the bug in the following code. *DataContainer* is a wrapper around the database providing the cache for the data fetched from the database.

calling *fetch* should fetch the data from the database via *DbConnection*. If the fetch succeeds, it should return *true*; otherwise it should return *false*. Calling *getData* should return cached data or throw an exception if the data has not been fetched yet.

```
function DataContainer(connectionString) {
  var dataFetched = false;
  var dbConnection = DbConnection(connectionString);
}

DataContainer.prototype.getData = function () {
  if (!this.dataFetched)
    throw "Data not fetched!";
  return this.data;
}

DataContainer.prototype.fetch = function () {
  this.dbConnection.getAllData(function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      delete this.data;
      this.dataFetched = false;
      return false;
    } else {
      this.data = result;
      this.dataFetched = true;
      return true;
    }
  });
}

// Mock of DbConnection for testing purposes:
function DbConnection(connectionString) { }

DbConnection.prototype.getAllData = function (callback) {
  callback(null, [1, 2, 3]);
}

//Expected: 1, 2, 3
var dc = new DataContainer('connection');
if (dc.fetch()) {
  var data = dc.getData();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i]);
  }
}
```

I fixed the code as much as I could including creating new *DbConnection* object in the constructor function, defining properties with *this* keyword instead of *var* in the constructor function, and binding *this* to the callback function while calling *getData* (look at the following code). The only remaining problem is how to call an asynchronous function (*getData*) inside a synchronous function?!

```
function DataContainer(connectionString) {
  this.dataFetched = false;
  this.dbConnection = new DbConnection(connectionString);
}

DataContainer.prototype.getData = function () {
  if (!this.dataFetched)
    throw "Data not fetched!";
  return this.data;
}

DataContainer.prototype.fetch = function () {
  this.dbConnection.getAllData(function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      delete this.data;
      this.dataFetched = false;
      return false;
    } else {
      this.data = result;
      this.dataFetched = true;
      return true;
      }
    }.bind(this));
}
```

*fetch* is an synchronous function and we are not allowed to make it asynchronous. *getData* is an asynchronous function and we are not allowed to make it synchronous. Now how we can use *getData* inside *fetch*???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetch` is synchronous, but `getAllData` is async, so the question is how do you make `getAllData` behave as if it were a synchronous function. One (and possibly the only) way you could achieve this is by using `async/await`:

```
DataContainer.prototype.fetch = async function fetch() {
  return await new Promise(resolve => {
      this.dbConnection.getAllData((err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          delete this.data;
          this.dataFetched = false;
        } else {
          this.data = result;
          this.dataFetched = true;
        }
        resolve(this.dataFetched);
      });
  });
}
```

This will allow the consuming code to treat the call as a synchronous operation